# How to cache a small piece of information in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a website that delivers a list of questions to users. This set of questions is the same for all users. I have these questions stored in a text file. The content of this file will not change while the server is running.

I cannot use a static page to display these questions because I have some logic to decide when to show which question.

I would like to cache these questions in memory (instead of reading the file off the hard drive every time a user connects). I am using Django 1.7.

I did read about caching from Django's website, I think the suggested methods (like memcached and database) are too heavy for my need. What would be a good solution for my situation? use a global variable?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you could create a RAM disc and save the file on it http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux

Comment: Not quite caching, but you could use a context processor. Or if you are using class-based views, you could extend get_context_data to define the questions in the response context.

Comment: I can't find a reason caching would be to heavy for your need, if you need to cache, use a cache engine, load the initial data, assign it to a cache with a key that can be easily tracked if the data has changed (maybe a hash of all the values), then if data changes, reload and regenerate the cache. If not, then declare the questions somewhere in your model and use them directly as variables (but I would avoid doing so, as it introduces dependencies in your core)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I will read more about this topic and give caching a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many caching back-ends you can use as listed in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/

I haven't tried the file system or local memory caching myself, I always needed memcached, but looks like they're available, and the rest is a piece of cake!

```
from django.core import cache

cache_key = 'questions'
questions = cache.cache.get(cache_key) # to get
if questions:
  # use questions you fetched from cache
else:
  questions = { 'question1': 'How are you?'} #Something serializable that has your questions
  cache.cache.set(cache_key, questions)
```